# Get application data in net frame via tshark command line

Tags: wireshark, network-protocols

Here I need parse a custom protocol in many .pcapng files , I want direct filter and output the application raw data via tshark command .

At first , I use the **"-e data.data"** option , but ,some of the application data could be decode as other protocol , and wouldn't be output by -e data.data.
Then , I find a way that special the **"disable-protocol"** file under wireshark profile folder,but ,I must take the profile file and deploy it before run the parse program on other PC.
And, I tried disable all the protocol except udp and tcp ,but it can't work.
I also disable the known conflict protocols , it works ,but there may be same mistake on other unknown protocol and the tshark's  output still can't be trust completely.

I works on Windows7 and wireshark 2.2.use python 2.7 for parse work.
In a summary , what I want is a portable command line that can flexible and direct output all data after UDP information in a net frame.
could I disable decode on some ports by just add options in command line?

**EDIT1:**
I find in wireshark 1.12,there is a **"Do not decode"** option in **"decode as..."** dialog , if enable it,the display is what I want.but in wireshark 2.2,they removed the option.and I still need a command line to do this filter.

Answer (score 0):

After 48 hours and 26 times viewed ,it still no response but one vote up.
I already give up this way, and decode the frame by myself.
what I want is the udp srcport and dstport, and the application data.
In actual , every net frame has a same length of header , so ,it's easy to strip the header by a fixed offset , and get the special data.
In my case , I just do some filter and use **-x** option for output.,as this:

> tshark -r xxx.pcapng -j udp -x

the output may looks like this:
[image]
(just for example,not real case)

Every line contains three parts :The first column is offset reference, the next 16 columns are bytes in hex , and the remains are the characters map to the data.
My code:

```
def load_tshark_data(tshark_file_path):
    tshark_exe = "c:/Program Files/Wireshark/tshark.exe"
    output = subprocess.check_output([
        tshark_exe,
        "-r",tshark_file_path,
        "-j","udp",
        "-x"
    ])
    hex_buff = ""
    line_buff = ""
    for c in output:
        if c == "\n":
            if len(line_buff) > 54:
                hex_buff += line_buff[5:53]
                line_buff = ''
            else:
                src_port = int(hex_buff[0x22*3 : 0x24*3].replace(" ",""),16)
                dst_port = int(hex_buff[0x24*3 : 0x26*3].replace(" ",""),16)
                app_data = hex_buff[0x2a*3 : ].strip(" ")
                hex_buff = ""
                yield [src_port, dst_port, app_data]
        else:
            line_buff += c
```

hope this can help any one also blocked by such a problem

Comment: I known the [pyshark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark) may be a better way to parse net frame in python , but it can't be compiled on my machine . this will be another question